# How to request the reason for an error on SSL_accept in OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, openssl

Using OpenSSL i am getting a negative return value performing `SSL_accept(ssl)` when establishing a DTLS "connection" to a client. I have checked the result of `SSL_get_error` and the result is 5, which corresponds to `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html) has suggested that i check `errno`, but that is set to 0. Just in case i have attempted to get it from `ERR_get_error`, but that returns 0 right away as well.

When i do `SSL_get_state(ssl)` i also receive 0.

How can i figure out which aspects of the code to look at to find a cause for the error? Is it something with certificate files? Is it something that i have not set up prior to calling `SSL_accept`?

Lots of useless code that doesn't provide anything:

```
    int ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if(ret != 1)
    {
        /*auto state = SSL_get_state(ssl);
        throw std::to_string(state);*/
        int sslError = SSL_get_error(ssl, ret);
        /*
        std::string er{"SSL_accept failed: "};
        while(sslError = ERR_get_error())
        {
            er += std::string{ERR_error_string(sslError, NULL)} + std::string("; ");
        }
        throw er;*/
        
        switch(sslError)
        {
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL"};
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ"};
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE"};
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN"};
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT"};
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT"};
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP"};
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                switch(errno)
                {
                    case EAFNOSUPPORT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EAFNOSUPPORT"};
                    case EADDRINUSE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EADDRINUSE"};
                    case EADDRNOTAVAIL:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EADDRNOTAVAIL"};
                    case EISCONN:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EISCONN"};
                    case E2BIG:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + E2BIG"};
                    case EDOM:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EDOM"};
                    case EFAULT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EFAULT"};
                    case EBADF:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EBADF"};
                    case EBADMSG:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EBADMSG"};
                    case EPIPE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EPIPE"};
                    case ECONNABORTED:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ECONNABORTED"};
                    case EALREADY:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EALREADY"};
                    case ECONNREFUSED:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ECONNREFUSED"};
                    case ECONNRESET:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ECONNRESET"};
                    case EXDEV:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EXDEV"};
                    case EDESTADDRREQ:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EDESTADDRREQ"};
                    case EBUSY:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EBUSY"};
                    case ENOTEMPTY:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTEMPTY"};
                    case ENOEXEC:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOEXEC"};
                    case EEXIST:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EEXIST"};
                    case EFBIG:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EFBIG"};
                    case ENAMETOOLONG:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENAMETOOLONG"};
                    case ENOSYS:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOSYS"};
                    case EHOSTUNREACH:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EHOSTUNREACH"};
                    case EIDRM:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EIDRM"};
                    case EILSEQ:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EILSEQ"};
                    case ENOTTY:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTTY"};
                    case EINTR:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EINTR"};
                    case EINVAL:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EINVAL"};
                    case ESPIPE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ESPIPE"};
                    case EIO:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EIO"};
                    case EISDIR:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EISDIR"};
                    case EMSGSIZE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EMSGSIZE"};
                    case ENETDOWN:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENETDOWN"};
                    case ENETRESET:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENETRESET"};
                    case ENETUNREACH:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENETUNREACH"};
                    case ENOBUFS:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOBUFS"};
                    case ECHILD:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ECHILD"};
                    case ENOLINK:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOLINK"};
                    //case ENOLOCK:
                    //  throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOLOCK"};
                    case ENOMSG:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOMSG"};
                    case ENODATA:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENODATA"};
                    case ENOPROTOOPT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOPROTOOPT"};
                    case ENOSPC:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOSPC"};
                    case ENOSR:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOSR"};
                    case ENODEV:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENODEV"};
                    case ENXIO:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENXIO"};
                    case ENOENT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOENT"};
                    case ESRCH:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ESRCH"};
                    case ENOTDIR:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTDIR"};
                    case ENOTSOCK:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTSOCK"};
                    case ENOSTR:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOSTR"};
                    case ENOTCONN:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTCONN"};
                    case ENOMEM:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOMEM"};
                    case ENOTSUP:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTSUP"};
                    case ECANCELED:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ECANCELED"};
                    case EINPROGRESS:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EINPROGRESS"};
                    case EPERM:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EPERM"};
                    //case EOPNOTSUPP:
                    //  throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EOPNOTSUPP"};
                    case EWOULDBLOCK:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EWOULDBLOCK"};
                    case EOWNERDEAD:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EOWNERDEAD"};
                    case EACCES:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EACCES"};
                    case EPROTO:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EPROTO"};
                    case EPROTONOSUPPORT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EPROTONOSUPPORT"};
                    case EROFS:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EROFS"};
                    case EDEADLK:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EDEADLK"};
                    //case EAGAIN:
                    //  throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EAGAIN"};
                    case ERANGE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ERANGE"};
                    case ENOTRECOVERABLE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENOTRECOVERABLE"};
                    case ETIME:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ETIME"};
                    case ETXTBSY:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ETXTBSY"};
                    case ETIMEDOUT:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ETIMEDOUT"};
                    case EMFILE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EMFILE"};
                    case ENFILE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ENFILE"};
                    case EMLINK:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EMLINK"};
                    case ELOOP:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + ELOOP"};
                    case EOVERFLOW:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EOVERFLOW"};
                    case EPROTOTYPE:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + EPROTOTYPE"};
                    default:
                        throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL + unknown error "}+std::to_string(errno);
                }
            default:
                throw std::string{"SSL_accept failed with unknown error "}+std::to_string(sslError);
        }
    }
```

I can see that a hello packet does arrive from the client with the following output from tshark:

```
1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    DTLS 253 Client Hello
```

I would be waiting for the server to send DTLSv1.0 78 Hello Verify Request, but it does not happen.

Comment: There is no way to answer this without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added lots of useless code that currently does nothing.

Comment: Usually if you get SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL then you are supposed to check errno. However there is a known issue where you can end up getting this error and 0 in errno if the client has abruptly closed the connection without first sending a "close_notify" alert.